# Disable syntax highlighter visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I love Visual Studio Code, but I can't seem to figure out how to disable this syntax highlight popup:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8e2X.jpg

I feel like I've disabled everything in the settings for editor. Is there a special setting to disable the syntax popup from just showing up??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following did the trick for me:

```
"editor.parameterHints": false,
```